# SSID retrieving in raspberry

Tags: ethernet, networking, bash

I'm trying to get my network's ESSID with `iwgetid` command, but
it does not work, either if I use:

`iwgetid`

or

`iwgetid eth0`

It displays .... nothing ... any idea what is going on?

Edit:

Thanks to all of you guys, you are right this works great for wireless cards (in my laptop works ok) but my Raspberry is on ethernet... any idea of a command I can use to get ESSID in raspberry, connected trough ethernet?

Answer (score 4):

As per `man` page of [`iwgetid`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iwgetid),

> iwgetid is used to find out the NWID, ESSID or AP/Cell Address of the
>   wireless network that is currently used.

and usage is as follow :

> iwgetid [interface] [--raw] [--scheme] [--ap] [--freq] [--mode]
>   [--protocol] [--channel]

Since `eth0` is not the wireless interface, it doesn't show any output. Try it with a wireless interface, for example, upon executing `iwgetid wlan0`, I got :

```
wlan0      ESSID:"MySSID"
```

In short, it works only for wireless interfaces and you have to mention that particular interface explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

If you want you use these utilities to get ssid.

`$ iwconfig wlan0 | grep essid`

or

`$ iw wlan0 link | grep ssid`

Answer (score 2):

iw- prefixed utilities get results on wireless interfaces.